# URL for page view interaction is giving me {{SiteName}} instead of website in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: xconnect, experience-profile, interaction

I have followed this doc article on how to create interaction with xConnect -> https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/interactions/add-interaction.html.

My code is run and I can see this interaction in Experience profile in Activity Tab and Visits section:

[image]

How can I get rid of {{SiteName}} and see website or any other site definition name?

Like here:

[image]

I am running this on `Sitecore 9.0.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found answer.

You need to add Webvisit into your interaction and specify SiteName there :)

```
// Create a new web visit facet model
var webVisitFacet = new WebVisit();

// Populate data about the web visit
webVisitFacet.Browser = new BrowserData() { BrowserMajorName = "Chrome", BrowserMinorName = "Desktop", BrowserVersion = "22.0" };
webVisitFacet.Language = "en";
webVisitFacet.OperatingSystem = new OperatingSystemData() { Name = "Windows", MajorVersion = "10", MinorVersion = "4" };
webVisitFacet.Referrer = "www.google.com";
webVisitFacet.Screen = new ScreenData() { ScreenHeight = 1080, ScreenWidth = 685 };
webVisitFacet.SearchKeywords = "sitecore";
webVisitFacet.SiteName = "website";

...
...

// Set web visit facet on interaction
client.SetWebVisit(webInteraction, webVisitFacet);
```

Take a look in below mentioned xConnect doc article for further details:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/interactions/add-events.html#adding-a-pageviewevent-to-an-interaction

Comment: how to get url which is beside sitename?